# No login possible with postfix/dovecot and mysql under IMAP

Tags: server, postfix, mail, dovecot

I did the following installation of my own mailserver with dovecot/postfix and MySQL:
https://thomas-leister.de/internet/mailserver-ubuntu-server-dovecot-postfix-mysql/

If you see the section of setting up the MySQL server, my first question is if my settings are okay. I've got three tables in my database `vmail` called `aliases`, `domains` and `users`. Into `domains` I set up my domain address which links to my server (e.g. mho.de). In `aliases` I set up which mail should be forwarded to another mail address and in users I set up user containing information about `username`, `domain` and the corresponding `password`.

Now if I want to setup an email account in a mail client, I get the following on the server and the client can't connect to the server:

```
Jun 17 17:48:47 vserver dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=from_ip, lip=dest_ip, TLS: Disconnected, session=<8mBXFAr87QDVkvRR>
```